# How to listen for HTTP pings in python docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, azure-webapps

This is my first time working with Azure webapps and docker containers. I created a tool that for reasons is running on a web app appservice plan in a Python Docker container. Testing this locally everything was good to go, but now after deploying I'm seeing stuff in the logs about how the container keeps shutting down because it's not responding to HTTP pings.

I didn't set up any type of listener in my code, but now I need to create one just to get past this. How can I make it so that it just listens for an HTTP ping and returns the response so that my container instance can get going?

I'm trying to do this locally, I exposed port 8000 in my dockerfile and tried using the code below, but any time I try and ping localhost/8000, I get a "Unknown host" error.

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
  print("serving at port", PORT)
  httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by ping, you mean actual ping command, it doesn't work like that. 
If you want to check your server and see it's up or not, try this:

```
curl localhost:8080
```

in the terminal if you are in Linux or Mac. Or open your browser and enter this in the browser:

```
localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thank you! That made much more sense, configured, and bypassed the error. Marking your answer as correct.